# jQuery plugin for dynamically sticky headers and footers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gui

I am creating a jQuery plugin to be used to stick the headers and footers of tables (or other list data) to the top and bottom of the viewport while scrolling. (i.e. scrolling down the page, the header sticks to the top of the viewport and footer is always visible while table is in view)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/rrzjaxuq/

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    // Defaults and constants
    var pluginName = 'stickyHooters',
        defaults = {
            footerSelector: 'tfoot',
            headerSelector: 'thead',
            top: '0',
            bottom: '0'
        },
        classNames = {
            outerWrapper: 'sticky-hooters_wrapper',
            innerWrapper: 'sticky-hooters_sticky-wrapper',
            innerWrapperHead: 'sticky-hooters_sticky-header',
            innerWrapperFoot: 'sticky-hooters_sticky-footer',
        };

    // StickyHooters constructor
    function StickyHooters(element, options) {
        var elmRect;

        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.footerElement = $(this.settings.footerSelector, this.element)[0];
        this.headerElement = $(this.settings.headerSelector, this.element)[0];
        this.isTable = this.element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table';

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        elmRect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.isVisible = function() {
            var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
            return elmRect.top < viewportHeight && elmRect.bottom > 0;
        };
        this.init();
    }

    $.extend(StickyHooters.prototype, {

        /**
         *  Initializes DOM and sets event listeners.
         *
         *  @method init
         */
        init: function() {
            // Add DOM wrapper to provide known reference point
            $(this.element).wrap($('<div></div>').addClass(classNames.outerWrapper));

            if (this.footerElement || this.headerElement) {

                // Clone, wrap, decorate and store references to header/footer.
                if (this.footerElement) {
                    this.setupHooter(true);
                }
                if (this.headerElement) {
                    this.setupHooter();
                }

                /*
                    Add throttled scroll event listener and trigger scroll
                    event to initialize sticky header/footer positions.
                */
                window.addEventListener('scroll', $.throttle(60, this.watchHooters.bind(this)));
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
            }
        },

        /**
         *  Decorates DOM elements to support sticky functionality.
         *
         *  @method setupHooter
         *  @param {Boolean} Is this a sticky footer?
         */
        setupHooter: function(isFooter) {
            var insertAction = isFooter ? 'insertAfter' : 'insertBefore',
                element = isFooter ? 'footerElement' : 'headerElement',
                wrapperClasses = [
                    classNames.innerWrapper,
                    isFooter ? classNames.innerWrapperFoot : classNames.innerWrapperHead
                ];

            /**
                1. Create and store header/footer clone
                2. Wrap with sticky-hooters DIV
                3. Conditionally wrap with TABLE (THEAD/TFOOT only)
                5. Set clone width equal to container and hide
                6. Append to DOM
             */
            this[element].stickyClone = $(this[element]).clone(true)
                .wrap(
                    $('<div></div>').css({
                        bottom: isFooter ? this.settings.bottom : 'auto',
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: !isFooter ? this.settings.top : 'auto'
                    }).addClass(wrapperClasses.join(' '))
                )
                .wrap(function () {
                        var classNames = this.element.getAttribute('class');
                        if (this.isTable) {
                            return $('<table></table>').addClass(classNames).css({
                                'table-layout': 'fixed'
                            });
                        }
                        return '';
                    }.bind(this)
                ).parents('.' + classNames.innerWrapper)
                .css({
                     width: $(this.element).parent().width(),
                     display: 'none'
                 })
                [insertAction](this.element)[0];
        },

        /**
         *  Hides inline element and displays sticky clone.
         *
         *  @method stick
         *  @param {HTMLElement} The header or footer item to be stuck.
         */
        stick: function(elem) {
            elem.isStuck = true;
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            elem.stickyClone.style.display = 'block';
        },

        /**
         *  Shows inline element and hides sticky clone.
         *
         *  @method unstick
         *  @param {HTMLElement} The header or footer item to be unstuck.
         */
        unstick: function(elem) {
            elem.isStuck = false;
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            elem.stickyClone.style.display = 'none';
        },

        /**
         *  If sticky footer is enabled, this method will be called
         *  on scroll to make any required updates to the footer.
         *
         *  @method watchFooter
         *  @param {HTMLElement} The sticky footer item to be processed.
         */
        watchFooter: function(footer, header) {
            var footAdjust = parseInt(this.settings.bottom, 10),
                footRect = footer.getBoundingClientRect(),
                headRect = header.getBoundingClientRect(),
                viewHeight = window.innerHeight;

            if (footer.isStuck) {
                /**
                    Unstick this sticky hooter's footer element if:
                        1. Footer has moved above bottom of viewport, OR ...
                        2. Header has scrolled to the footer, OR ...
                        3. Sticky hooter element is no longer visible in the viewport
                 */
                if (footRect.top <= viewHeight - footRect.height - footAdjust ||
                    headRect.bottom > viewHeight - footRect.height - footAdjust ||
                    !this.isVisible()) {
                    this.unstick(footer);
                }
            } else {
                /**
                    Stick this sticky hooter's footer element if:
                        1. Footer element is below bottom of the viewport, AND ...
                        2. Header is above sticky footer, AND ...
                        3. Sticky hooter element is visible in the viewport
                 */
                if (footRect.top > viewHeight - footRect.height - footAdjust &&
                    headRect.bottom <= viewHeight - footRect.height / 2 - footAdjust &&
                    this.isVisible()) {
                    this.stick(footer);
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         *  If sticky footer is enabled, this method will be called
         *  on scroll to make any required updates to the footer.
         */
        watchHeader: function(header, footer) {
            var headAdjust = parseInt(this.settings.top, 10),
                footRect = footer ? footer.getBoundingClientRect() : null,
                headRect = header.getBoundingClientRect(),
                footOffset = footRect ? footRect.top : this.element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
                headHeight = footRect ? headRect.height / 2 : headRect.height;

            if (header.isStuck) {
                if (headRect.top > headAdjust || footOffset < headHeight + headAdjust) {
                    this.unstick(header);
                }
            } else {
                if (headRect.top <= parseInt(this.settings.top, 10) && footOffset > headHeight + headAdjust) {
                    this.stick(header);
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         *  Delegates scroll event handling to specific header
         *  and footer DOM manipulation methods.
         *
         *  @parameter {UIEvent} jQuery scroll Event object with injected
         *                       instance reference.
         */
        watchHooters: function(/*event*/) {
            if (!!this.footerElement) {
                this.watchFooter(this.footerElement, this.headerElement);
            }

            if (!!this.headerElement) {
                this.watchHeader(this.headerElement, this.footerElement);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
        Lightweight wrapper around the constructor,
        preventing multiple instantiations.
    */
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new StickyHooters(this, options));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: To all those thinking this code has a silly name, that's OK, you can think that, but, it is a concatenation of the *H* from "Header", and the *ooter* from "footer", and it's just the way it is. Comments making fun of that, or flags on such comments will simply be removed/declined. It is what it is.